Do all cases in a switch need to be comptime known in Zig?
const std = @import("std");
const Allocator = std.mem.Allocator;

pub fn main() !void {
    const str = "[1,2,3]";
    parseSlice(str);
}

fn foo(_: u8) bool {
    return true;
}

fn parseSlice(s: []const u8) void {
    for (s) |c| {
        switch (c) {
            foo(c) => {},
            else => {},
        }
    }
}

The above code fails to compile, instead if I replace the switch case with a range or a constant it works
This is the error that is being printed
main.zig:16:17: error: unable to resolve comptime value
            foo(c) => {},
                ^
main.zig:16:17: note: argument to function being called at comptime must be comptime-known
referenced by:
    main: main.zig:6:5
    callMain: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zig/0.12.0/lib/zig/std/start.zig:511:32
    remaining reference traces hidden; use '-freference-trace' to see all reference traces




'yes' is unfortunately a bit too short for an answer.

Could you also please elaborate on what you're trying to do here? switch(c) { true => ...} wouldn't work, so even if you could put a function there that still wouldn't make any sense.

The function figures out if c is a digit, initially I was making a call to std.ascii.isDigit

I know what the function does, but what are you trying to accomplish by putting it into the left hand side of a case prong? As you already know, this is an invalid construct. I don't know what you wanted it to do, could you please explain?

Just wanted to evaluate a boolean condition, essentially check if it’s a digit and parse it as a number, else not do anything. Well in Golang your switch conditions can be multiple boolean expressions. So maybe I thought the same thing would work in Zig

Yes. This is described in the zig documentation in the switch section:
    const b = switch(a) {
        // ...
        // Switching on arbitrary expressions is allowed as long as the
        // expression is known at compile-time.
        zz => zz,
        blk: {
            const d: u32 = 5;
            const e: u32 = 100;
            break :blk d + e;
        } => 107,
    };

